# Error: Cannot find module '/app/wait-for-it.sh"'

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to dockerization my backend server.
my stack is nodejs-nestjs with redis and postgres
here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:15
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY wait-for-it.sh ./
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g npm@7.22.0
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-it.sh .

EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm run start:prod"]
```

and here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  redis-service:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    container_name: redis-container
    ports: 
      - 127.0.0.1:6379:6379
    expose:
      - 6379
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: postgres-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
      - DB_NAME = db
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:5432:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  oms-be:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis-service
    environment:
    - DB_HOST=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD = 1234
    - POSTGRES_USER=root
    - AUTH_REDIS_HOST=redis-service
    - DB_NAME = db
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "sh", "-c", "npm run start:prod"]
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up`
I got this error :

```
taching to oms-be-oms-be-1, postgres-container, redis-container
redis-container     | 1:C 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.730 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-container     | 1:C 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.730 # Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis-container     | 1:C 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.730 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis-container     | 1:M 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.731 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis-container     | 1:M 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.731 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis-container     | 1:M 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.731 # Server initialized
redis-container     | 1:M 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.731 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis-container     | 1:M 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.732 * The AOF directory appendonlydir doesn't exist
redis-container     | 1:M 05 Jun 2022 00:35:16.732 * Ready to accept connections
postgres-container  | 
postgres-container  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres-container  | 
postgres-container  | 2022-06-05 00:35:16.824 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027) 10.3.1 20211027, 64-bit
postgres-container  | 2022-06-05 00:35:16.824 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres-container  | 2022-06-05 00:35:16.824 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres-container  | 2022-06-05 00:35:16.827 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres-container  | 2022-06-05 00:35:16.833 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-06-05 00:34:36 UTC
postgres-container  | 2022-06-05 00:35:16.836 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
oms-be-oms-be-1     | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
oms-be-oms-be-1     |   throw err;
oms-be-oms-be-1     |   ^
oms-be-oms-be-1     | 
oms-be-oms-be-1     | Error: Cannot find module '/app/wait-for-it.sh"'
oms-be-oms-be-1     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
oms-be-oms-be-1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
oms-be-oms-be-1     |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
oms-be-oms-be-1     |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
oms-be-oms-be-1     |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
oms-be-oms-be-1     |   requireStack: []
oms-be-oms-be-1     | }
oms-be-oms-be-1 exited with code 1
```

I tried to build it without `wait-for-it.sh` and it was complaining that the server cannot connect to the Postgres DB and Redis, so I added `wait-for-it.sh` file to make it wait until the Redis and the Postgres DB are up, but I got the above error
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Two things: (1) There's a missing `"` in your `docker-compose.yaml` file in the `command` entry for the `oms-be` service. Do you get the same error if you resolve that problem? And (2) Please include your complete `Dockerfile`, including the `FROM` line.

Comment: @larsks, after adding the `"` I am still getting the same error. 
is it `build: .` not enough? sorry for my lack of knowledge I am still learning about docker and docker-compose

Comment: @larsks I modified the question, Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Your updated question still shows the same syntax missing quote in the `command:` for the `oms-be` container, and I think that's the problem. If I run use your `docker-compose.yaml` as written, I see the same error you do. If I fix the `command:` to include the missing quote, it works correctly.

Comment: @larsks I did add it, and yet it is not working, I am still getting the same error. does that have anything to do with my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yaml` in order to test things out on my system. I have this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "echo \"Example build command\"",
    "start:prod": "sleep inf"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY wait-for-it.sh ./
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-it.sh .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3333
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "npm run start:prod"]
```

And this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
  oms-be:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    command: [./wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "sh", "-c", "npm run start:prod"]
```

Note that the `command:` on the final line there has the missing quote. If I try to bring this up using `docker-compose up`, I see:

```
oms-be_1    | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
oms-be_1    |   throw err;
oms-be_1    |   ^
oms-be_1    |
oms-be_1    | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/wait-for-it.sh"'
oms-be_1    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
oms-be_1    |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
oms-be_1    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
oms-be_1    |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
oms-be_1    |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
oms-be_1    |   requireStack: []
oms-be_1    | }
```

If I correct the syntax so that we have:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  postgres:
    image: docker.io/postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
  oms-be:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "sh", "-c", "npm run start:prod"]
```

Then it runs successfully:

```
oms-be_1    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for postgres:5432
oms-be_1    | wait-for-it.sh: postgres:5432 is available after 0 seconds
oms-be_1    |
oms-be_1    | > example@1.0.0 start:prod
oms-be_1    | > sleep inf
oms-be_1    |
```

The difference in behavior is due to the `ENTRYPOINT` script in the underlying `node:15` image, which includes this logic:

```
if [ "${1#-}" != "${1}" ] || [ -z "$(command -v "${1}")" ]; then
  set -- node "$@"
fi
```

That says, essentially:

- **IF** the first parameter starts with `-`
- **OR** There is no command matching `$1`
- **THEN** try starting the command with `node`

With the missing `"`, you end up with an argument that doesn't match any valid commands, which is why you end up with an error in which `node` is trying to run the `wait-for-it.sh` script.

Comment: I added the same script that you did and yet I am getting the following error, the database is running, and Redis too, but still the same error appears

Comment: Thanks @larsks, it is working now, I should've deleted the docker images before re-trying again